# Regex: Get all instances and variations

Tags: regex

So, I'm trying to get these different scenarios:

1. square brackets with numbers inside e.g. [1] or [1111] or [1.2]
2. number 1 (above) followed by a colon e.g. [1]: or [1111]:
3. number 2 (above) followed by any length of numbers e.g. [111]:123
4. number 3 (above) followed by a space(s) and then numbers e.g. [111]: 27

Test string:

`time sheets..."[8]: 27  The ending sm testing [21] [2222] [22], [222]:22:`

I want to replace all matches with an empty string

Result:

`time sheets..."  The ending sm testing   , :`

My current pattern:

`\[(.*?)\](?::?|:[0-9]+?)`

Comment: Something like this should do, if I understand you correctly: `\[[^]]+\](?:: ?[0-9]*)?`. I made the colon-space-nrs part optional and switched the lazy class in the beginning for a negative class (the latter for performance).

Comment: @oriberu Hey, I thought your comment was working, but, it doesn't seem to be catching [8]:22 https://regex101.com/r/sI2qiM/1

Comment: You can use `\h?` instead of ` ?` to catch differently encoded horizontal space too, which I presume is the issue there.

Comment: @oriberu Yeah, that fixed the issue I was seeing

Comment: Here is an updated expression to account for your comments: `\[[0-9.]+\](?::(?:\h*[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*)?)?`. Any amount of horizontal space `\h*` is used to limit matching the sequence to one line and not catch digits at the beginning of another line, and grouping `(?:,[0-9]+)*` is used to get an optional amount of a comma followed by digits, but never one without the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)]:?(?:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v09AWG/1).

*Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: an int or float number
- `]` - a `]` char
- `:?` - an optional `:` char
- `(?:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: an int or float number

**Note**: If the last number can only occur after a `:`, you need to slightly amend the above regex:

```
\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)](?::(?:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?)?
```

where the `:?(...)?` part is converted to `(:(...)?)?`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v09AWG/2).

Comment: Stribizew I don't know why, but it's not quite working with the text I'm looking at:
https://regex101.com/r/iTocT6/1

Comment: @Daltron That is a PCRE fiddle, so to make `\s` match any Unicode whitespace, you need to use the `u` flag, see [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/iTocT6/2).

Comment: Stribizew I can see it working on the demo site, but in my app, I get an error that says:
"Invalid regular expression: /\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)](?::(?:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?)?/: Lone quantifier brackets (2:15)"

Comment: @Daltron You forgot to escape the square brackets which you want to match literally there. Either that or the escapes were somehow removed.

Comment: @Daltron The `[` is special outside of character classes, it must be escaped. `]` is considered not special outside of character classes, but since I do not know your regex flavor, you may also escape `]` and use `\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\](?::(?:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?)?`. Not sure it is the problem...

Comment: I usually escape both in a set of literal brackets, even if it's not strictly necessary for the closing one, just to keep better track of what happens in the expression.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, that was it. One more addition, I need to also include this case: 
[111]:28,29 ",29" at the end, there may be multiple e.g. [111]:29,28,100

Comment: @Daltron See https://regex101.com/r/v09AWG/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hey, that did it. Awesome! Do you have a Fiverr account by chance? The next one should be paid. Haha!